# Neocomplete and Eclim don't work together

Tags: eclim, neocomplcache

with the default set up, there nothing shows about the auto completion,either no autocomplete shows up nor `<C-X><C-U>` key, the later shows `"pattern not found"`,  Is there anyone can tell me how to make it working?

here my vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
set laststatus=2
set encoding=utf-8
set guifont=Anonymous\ Pro\ for\ Powerline:h13
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
if has("gui_running")
    set guioptions=egmrt
    set transparency=10
    set guifont=menlo:h14
endif

imap jj <Esc>
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
filetype off                   " required!

 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
 call vundle#rc()

 " let Vundle manage Vundle
 " required! 
 Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

 " My Bundles here:
 " original repos on github
 Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar'
 Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails'
 Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplcache'
 Bundle 'nanotech/jellybeans.vim'
 Bundle 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete'
 Bundle 'osyo-manga/neocomplcache-clang_complete'
 colorscheme jellybeans
 Bundle 'godlygeek/tabular'
 Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'
 Bundle 'tpope/vim-haml'
 Bundle 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
 Bundle 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
 Bundle 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'

 " vim-scripts repos
 Bundle 'DrawIt'
 Bundle 'tComment'
 Bundle 'sudo.vim'
 Bundle 'Align'

 " non github repos
 "Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'

 filetype plugin indent on     " required!

 nmap 88 :TagbarToggle<CR>
 nmap 99 :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
" use neocomplcache & clang_complete

" add neocomplcache option
let g:neocomplcache_force_overwrite_completefunc=1

" add clang_complete option
 let g:clang_complete_auto=1

" Disable AutoComplPop. 
let g:acp_enableAtStartup = 0 
" Use neocomplcache. 
let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1 
" Use smartcase. 
let g:neocomplcache_enable_smart_case = 1 
" Use camel case completion. 
let g:neocomplcache_enable_camel_case_completion = 1 
" Use underbar completion. 
let g:neocomplcache_enable_underbar_completion = 1 
" Set minimum syntax keyword length. 
let g:neocomplcache_min_syntax_length = 3 
let g:neocomplcache_lock_buffer_name_pattern = '\*ku\*' 

" Define dictionary. 
let g:neocomplcache_dictionary_filetype_lists = { 
    \ 'default' : '', 
    \ 'vimshell' : $HOME.'/.vimshell_hist', 
    \ 'scheme' : $HOME.'/.gosh_completions' 
    \ } 


" Define keyword. 
if !exists('g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns') 
    let g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns = {} 
endif 
let g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns['default'] = '\h\w*' 

" Plugin key-mappings. 
imap <C-k>     <Plug>(neocomplcache_snippets_expand) 
smap <C-k>     <Plug>(neocomplcache_snippets_expand) 
inoremap <expr><C-g>     neocomplcache#undo_completion() 
inoremap <expr><C-l>     neocomplcache#complete_common_string() 

" SuperTab like snippets behavior. 
"imap <expr><TAB> neocomplcache#sources#snippets_complete#expandable() ? "\<Plug>(neocomplcache_snippets_expand)" : pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>" 

" Recommended key-mappings. 
" <CR>: close popup and save indent. 
inoremap <expr><CR>  neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() . "\<CR>" 
" <TAB>: completion. 
inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>" 
" <C-h>, <BS>: close popup and delete backword char. 
inoremap <expr><C-h> neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>" 
inoremap <expr><BS> neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>" 
inoremap <expr><C-y>  neocomplcache#close_popup() 
inoremap <expr><C-e>  neocomplcache#cancel_popup() 



" AutoComplPop like behavior. 
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1 

" Shell like behavior(not recommended). 
"set completeopt+=longest 
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1 
"let g:neocomplcache_disable_auto_complete = 1 
"inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<TAB>" 
"inoremap <expr><CR>  neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() . "\<CR>" 

" Enable omni completion. 
autocmd FileType css setlocal omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS 
autocmd FileType html,markdown setlocal omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags 
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS 
autocmd FileType python setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete 
autocmd FileType xml setlocal omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags 

" Enable heavy omni completion. 
if !exists('g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns') 
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns = {} 
endif 
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.ruby = '[^. *\t]\.\w*\|\h\w*::' 
"autocmd FileType ruby setlocal omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete 
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.php = '[^. \t]->\h\w*\|\h\w*::'
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your vimrc

`let g:EclimCompletionMethod = 'omnifunc'`

Check out http://eclim.org/vim/code_completion.html for more information.